# Show Bluetooth / Volume in menu bar Apple Script

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, macos-catalina, menubar

I have a working script that I would like to see if there is a way to hide or simply have the script run in the background. The current working script physically activates the pane thus the user is seeing it happen in front of them.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane "Bluetooth"
    delay 1
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        set toggleBluetooth to the checkbox "Show Bluetooth in menu bar" of the window "Bluetooth"
        click toggleBluetooth
    end tell
end tell
```

I've also found a way to turn on certain things instantly and was wondering if there was a way to take this and make it work with the bluetooth and volume.

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell Finder preferences
        set desktop shows hard disks to true
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Does this help? [Menu bar customization](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/10576/menu-bar-customization)

Answer (score 0):

This following AppleScript code can be used to toggle the Bluetooth menu bar item on and off, without bringing System Preferences to the front.

```
if application "System Preferences" is running then
    do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    repeat until application "System Preferences" is not running
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
end if

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Main" of pane id "com.apple.preferences.Bluetooth"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until checkbox "Show Bluetooth in menu bar" of window "Bluetooth" of application process "System Preferences" exists
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click checkbox "Show Bluetooth in menu bar" of window "Bluetooth" of application process "System Preferences"
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

And this will do the exact same thing for the volume icon in the menu bar

```
if application "System Preferences" is running then
    do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    repeat until application "System Preferences" is not running
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
end if

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until checkbox "Show volume in menu bar" of window "Sound" of application process "System Preferences" exists
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click checkbox "Show volume in menu bar" of window "Sound" of application process "System Preferences"
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```